# How do I pass a Path to Command::arg?

Tags: rust

I'm getting back into Rust after a long break. I'm trying to do the following:

```
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("SOME_DIRECTORY").unwrap();
    for path in paths {
        let full_path = path.unwrap().path();
        process(full_path);
    }
}

fn process<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) {
    let output = Command::new("gunzip")
        .arg("--stdout")
        .arg(path.as_os_str())
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `as_os_str` found for type `P` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:50:23
   |
50 |             .arg(path.as_os_str())
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

`Command::Arg` is expecting an OsStr, but I am not able to convert the Path into an OsStr for some reason (something to do with the AsRef?)

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=843baddc91fce15c667dc20ed36f3743&version=stable&mode=debug ?

Comment: So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the signature for [`Command::arg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg), you can see what types it accepts. It is any type that can be referenced as an `OsStr`:

```
pub fn arg<S: AsRef<OsStr>>(&mut self, arg: S) -> &mut Command
```

If you look at the [implementors of `AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#implementors), you will see that `Path` is one:

```
impl AsRef<OsStr> for PathBuf {}
impl AsRef<OsStr> for Path {}
```

Circling back to your question:

> How do I pass a Path to Command::arg?

By *passing a `Path` to `arg`*:

```
fn process(path: &Path) {
    let output = Command::new("gunzip")
        .arg("--stdout")
        .arg(path)
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");
}
```

---

Your issue is that you have accepted a generic `P` that is only guaranteed to have one trait implemented: `P: AsRef<Path>`. *It's not a `Path`*. That's why the error message tells you there's no method `as_os_str`

> ```
> error[E0599]: no method named `as_os_str` found for type `P` in the current scope
> ```

The only thing you can do for this type is to call `as_ref`. This will return a `&Path`:

```
let output = Command::new("gunzip")
    .arg("--stdout")
    .arg(path.as_ref())
    .output()
    .expect("failed to execute process");
```